# Hiding a weapon in a soon-hostile city

Tags: science-based, warfare, earth, cities, artificial-intelligence

I am part of a group of scientists working for a private military research company. We were presented with a  substance that we were able to make into a powerful weapon, but we failed to replicate the substance itself and we used up all of it. The weapon we made included an artificial intelligence, about as smart as a child, and we grew very attached to it.

The thing is, our nation is in the middle of a war and the enemy has made a sudden push forward that encircled an area - including the city we're in. We have debated what to do with the weapon since we've been cut off from command and have no orders for this situation. We don't want the weapon to fall into enemy hands or destroy it since we care about it. The war has been going for some time, so we know how the enemy operates. They will allow civilians to cross the border,  but they are searched and all valuables are confiscated. The weapon at its most compact can fit into a cubic crate 1.5 meter (5 feet) at a side, so there is no chance of getting it out undetected. The AI can enter a sleep mode, so it won't get lonely.

We have decided to hide the weapon somewhere in the city or close by and go get it later. The tides of war are slowly turning, and we expect our side to retake the city eventually - but that might take years, or even decades. The enemy will be poking around in the city while they can, but  they have no reason to know of the weapons existence or go look for it especially.

Where do we hide it so that it will not be found for decades of enemy occupation, but will be recoverable and intact when our side controls the city again? The city would be modern-day Prague, or another city of similar size and advancement. We have a week to prepare before the enemy takes the city, a few days less if we want to hide it somewhere in the country.

Hard mode: the weapon needs electricity to not die, about as much as a desktop computer, but has batteries that take a day to charge and last a week.

Comment: The time-tested method of hiding a treasure is to bury it. It works. We are still finding treasures which were buried millenia ago...

Comment: Echoing AlexP, Buried weapon caches is a time tested method, and they have even found ones still in good condition from WWII

Comment: And no matter what solution you go with I strongly recommend the scientists teach the AI before hiding it not to talk to strangers.  That way if it is found and turned on, it will not start helping the enemy.

Answer (score 5):

Hide it in plain sight.

Alter it's appearance to make it look like a statue or a broken piece of equipment.

As a broken piece of equipment, you could hide it in a maintenance shed.

As a statue, you could hide it in a museum in a display, or even in a park.  You could even encase it metal or concrete and disguise it as the pedestal of a statue.

Hide it without making it look like it's hidden is the key.

Comment: and for hard mode, disguise it as something even the enemy won't want to turn off, dismantle, move, or destroy for any reason.

Comment: don't overdo the "broken piece of equipment" look... during a war scrap metal is a valuable good.

Answer (score 2):

I can come up with 3 solutions to hide the weapon: the 'in plain sight', the 'public figure', and the 'distraction & extraction'.

**A)** in plain sight: fairly self-explanatory, you hide the weapon as something people take little notice of. A work of art, a pile of junk... you name it, and as long as you don't draw too much attention to it, you can probably disguise your weapon as it. If you can hide it somewhere near a power plant / somewhere that uses a lot of energy, you can easily siphon a little off without anyone noticing.

**B)** public figure: whereas the key to hiding something right under people's noses, the key to this idea is to make sure EVERYBODY knows what your robot is. Broadcast it! Let the poplace, both yours and the invader's, know that you have develped an AI as smart as a child! Just leave out the bit about it being a weapon. But here's the key - it has to be neutral. That way, you don't have to hide it. Nobody suspects it, but nobody wants to destroy it either. If it doesn't oppose anyone, it should hopefully remain safe.

**C)** distraction & extraction: this one is highly dependant on the size of the enemy's border force, and is the least likely to work, but I mght as well add it here anyway. You attempt to pass through an area with a weak border force, and deliberately attract their attention by having something valuable and potentially dangerous for them to confiscate. Meanwhile, the rest of your team attempts to reach a nearby city that hasn't het been attacked (If the attack is happening in the Czech Republic as the mention of Prague would suggest, I would put forward Ústí nad Labem as the closest major city, although I could easily be missing one closer). They deliver the weapon there. As I say, risky and unlikey to work.

Comment: I don't agree with B. A so powerful AI would attract enemy scientist to study it and make even better ones, and use them for weapons.

Comment: @b.Lorenz That's fair enough. I suppose it could be protected with the bodyguard levels we use for politicians, but then that would attract suspicion about exactly WHY it needed so much protection in the first place. I would propose that you don't present it as anything particularly special (it simply searches a database to find the most apprpriate response for a situation. Not an AI, but a simple robot) but still make it well known. As most celebrities show, things don't need to be special to be famous.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

1. Break the weapon into parts and hide it all over the city so if someone finds it they think its junk or just something being invented
2. Bury it in a sealed waterproof / airproof bag under the basement of a house owned
3. Create an equivalent of a [priest hole](http://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryUK/HistoryofEngland/Priests-Holes/) to keep the equipment hidden and people hidden.
4. Create a hidden area like [Anne Frank](https://images.trvl-media.com/media/content/shared/images/travelguides/destination/178229/Anne-Frank-House-28262.jpg) and her family used to hide from the Nazi's. If you created this area above an office or factory that used alot of power such as the equivalent of say 50 desktop computers then the extra power from one should not be noticeable and there would be no batteries being taken in or out of it, you could just brick the area up and leave it for years until the war was over. Could work well if buried under a basement floor and concreted over.